# How to read xml file having different hierarchy in .net

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, out-of-memory

I have big 7GB xml file ,and i am pasting small portion here

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <bulkFile xmlns:un="utranNrm.xsd"
        xmlns:es="Attributes.15.25.xsd"
        xmlns:xn="generic.xsd" xmlns:gn="geran.xsd" xmlns="configData.xsd">
      <fileHeader fileFormatVersion="32.615 V4.5" Name="Wmart"/>
      <configData dnPrefix="Undefined">
        <xn:SubNetwork id="M_ROOT">
          <xn:VsDataContainer id="1">
            <xn:attributes>
              <xn:vsDataType>vsDataAreas</xn:vsDataType>
              <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>SpecificAttributes</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
              <es:vsDataAreas/>
            </xn:attributes>
            <xn:VsDataContainer id="424_2_2">
              <xn:attributes>
                <xn:vsDataType>vsDataPlmn</xn:vsDataType>
                <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>SpecificAttributes</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                <es:vsDataPlmn>
                  <es:userLabel></es:userLabel>
                  <es:mcc>424</es:mcc>
                  <es:mnc>2</es:mnc>
                  <es:mncLength>2</es:mncLength>
                  <es:aliasPlmnIdentities>
                    <es:mcc>424</es:mcc>
                    <es:mnc>2</es:mnc>
                    <es:mncLength>2</es:mncLength>
                  </es:aliasPlmnIdentities>
                </es:vsDataPlmn>
              </xn:attributes>
              <xn:VsDataContainer id="10">
                <xn:attributes>
                  <xn:vsDataType>vsDataLocationArea</xn:vsDataType>
                  <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>SpecificAttributes</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                  <es:vsDataLocationArea>
                    <es:userLabel></es:userLabel>
                    <es:lac>10</es:lac>
                    <es:t3212>10</es:t3212>
                    <es:att>1</es:att>
                  </es:vsDataLocationArea>
                </xn:attributes>
              </xn:VsDataContainer>
            </xn:VsDataContainer>
          </xn:VsDataContainer>
          <xn:SubNetwork id="G-Mum">
            <xn:attributes>
              <xn:userDefinedNetworkType>SiteSolutions</xn:userDefinedNetworkType>
              <xn:userLabel>G-Mum</xn:userLabel>
            </xn:attributes>
            <xn:MeContext id="32509_I_East">
              <xn:VsDataContainer id="23502_I_AAN_UAEU_Crescent_East">
                <xn:attributes>
                  <xn:vsDataType>vsDataMeContext</xn:vsDataType>
                  <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>EricssonSpecificAttributes.15.25</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                  <es:vsDataMeContext>
                    <es:userLabel>23502_I_AAN_UAEU_Crescent_East</es:userLabel>
                    <es:ipAddress>10.235.20.10</es:ipAddress>
                    <es:neMIMversion>vF.1.108</es:neMIMversion>
                    <es:lostSynchronisation>SYNCHRONISED</es:lostSynchronisation>
                    <es:bcrLastChange>1474785017888</es:bcrLastChange>
                    <es:bctLastChange>1470699087457</es:bctLastChange>
                    <es:multiStandardRbs6k>false</es:multiStandardRbs6k>
                    <es:mixedModeRadio>false</es:mixedModeRadio>
                    <es:mirrorMIBversion>F.1.100.S.1.6</es:mirrorMIBversion>
                    <es:stnNodes></es:stnNodes>
                  </es:vsDataMeContext>
                </xn:attributes>
              </xn:VsDataContainer>
              <xn:ManagedElement id="1">
                <xn:attributes>
                </xn:attributes>
                <xn:VsDataContainer id="1">
                  <xn:attributes>
                    <xn:vsDataType>vsDataManagedElement</xn:vsDataType>
                    <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>Attributes.15.25.xsd</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                    <es:vsDataManagedElement>
                      <es:siteRef>SubNetwork=M_ROOT,Site=32509_I_East</es:siteRef>
                      <es:productType>Node</es:productType>
                      <es:productName>RBS6601L</es:productName>
                      <es:productNumber></es:productNumber>
                      <es:productRevision></es:productRevision>
                      <es:prodDesignation>0</es:prodDesignation>
                    </es:vsDataManagedElement>
                  </xn:attributes>
                </xn:VsDataContainer>
                .
                .
                <xn:VsDataContainer id="1">
                  <xn:attributes>
                    <xn:vsDataType>vsDataENodeBFunction</xn:vsDataType>
                    <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>Attributes.15.25.xsd</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                    <es:vsDataENodeBFunction>
                      <es:userLabel></es:userLabel>
                      <es:dscpLabel>24</es:dscpLabel>
                      <es:dnsLookupOnTai>1</es:dnsLookupOnTai>
                      <es:eNBId>32509</es:eNBId>
                    </es:vsDataENodeBFunction>
                  </xn:attributes>
                  <xn:VsDataContainer id="BC_3250_32509_L1_B">
                    <xn:attributes>
                      <xn:vsDataType>vsDataEUtranCellFDD</xn:vsDataType>
                      <es:earfcndl>1651</es:earfcndl>
                      <es:earfcnul>19651</es:earfcnul>
                    </xn:attributes>
                  </xn:VsDataContainer>
                  ..
                  <xn:VsDataContainer id="BD_4250_32509_L1_B">
                    <xn:attributes>
                      <xn:vsDataType>vsDataEUtranCellFDD</xn:vsDataType>
                      <es:earfcndl>1651</es:earfcndl>
                      <es:earfcnul>19651</es:earfcnul>
                    </xn:attributes>
                  </xn:VsDataContainer>

                  <xn:VsDataContainer id="CC_3250_32509_L1_C">
                    <xn:attributes>
                      <xn:vsDataType>testranCellFDD</xn:vsDataType>
                      <es:earfcndl>165</es:earfcndl>
                      <es:earfcnul>19651</es:earfcnul>
                    </xn:attributes>
                  </xn:VsDataContainer>
                </xn:VsDataContainer>
                ..

              </xn:ManagedElement>
            </xn:MeContext>
 <xn:MeContext id="32509_I_west">
          <xn:VsDataContainer id="32509_I_AAN_UAEU_Crescent_East">
            <xn:attributes>
              <xn:vsDataType>vsDataMeContext</xn:vsDataType>
              <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>Attributes.15.25</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
              <es:vsDataMeContext>
                <es:userLabel>32509_I_AAN_UAEU_Crescent_East</es:userLabel>
                <es:ipAddress>10.235.20.10</es:ipAddress>
                <es:neMIMversion>vF.1.108</es:neMIMversion>
                <es:lostSynchronisation>SYNCHRONISED</es:lostSynchronisation>
                <es:bcrLastChange>1474785017888</es:bcrLastChange>
                <es:bctLastChange>1470699087457</es:bctLastChange>
                <es:multiStandardRbs6k>false</es:multiStandardRbs6k>
                <es:mixedModeRadio>false</es:mixedModeRadio>
                <es:mirrorMIBversion>F.1.100.S.1.6</es:mirrorMIBversion>
                <es:stnNodes></es:stnNodes>
              </es:vsDataMeContext>
            </xn:attributes>
          </xn:VsDataContainer>
          <xn:ManagedElement id="1">
            <xn:attributes>
            </xn:attributes>
            <xn:VsDataContainer id="1">
              <xn:attributes>
                <xn:vsDataType>vsDataManagedElement</xn:vsDataType>
                <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>Attributes.15.25.xsd</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                <es:vsDataManagedElement>
                  <es:siteRef>SubNetwork=M_ROOT,Site=32509_I_East</es:siteRef>
                  <es:productType>Node</es:productType>
                  <es:productName>RBS6601L</es:productName>
                  <es:productNumber></es:productNumber>
                  <es:productRevision></es:productRevision>
                  <es:prodDesignation>0</es:prodDesignation>
                </es:vsDataManagedElement>
              </xn:attributes>
            </xn:VsDataContainer>
            .
            .
            <xn:VsDataContainer id="1">
              <xn:attributes>
                <xn:vsDataType>vsDataENodeBFunction</xn:vsDataType>
                <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>Attributes.15.25.xsd</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                <es:vsDataENodeBFunction>
                  <es:userLabel></es:userLabel>
                  <es:dscpLabel>24</es:dscpLabel>
                  <es:dnsLookupOnTai>1</es:dnsLookupOnTai>
                  <es:eNBId>32509</es:eNBId>
                </es:vsDataENodeBFunction>
              </xn:attributes>
              <xn:VsDataContainer id="CC_3250_32509_L1_B">
                <xn:attributes>
                  <xn:vsDataType>vsDataEUtranCellFDD</xn:vsDataType>
                  <es:earfcndl>1651</es:earfcndl>
                  <es:earfcnul>19651</es:earfcnul>
                </xn:attributes>
              </xn:VsDataContainer>
              ..
              <xn:VsDataContainer id="CD_4250_32509_L1_B">
                <xn:attributes>
                  <xn:vsDataType>vsDataEUtranCellFDD</xn:vsDataType>
                  <es:earfcndl>1651</es:earfcndl>
                  <es:earfcnul>19651</es:earfcnul>
                </xn:attributes>
              </xn:VsDataContainer>

              <xn:VsDataContainer id="DC_3250_32509_L1_C">
                <xn:attributes>
                  <xn:vsDataType>testranCellFDD</xn:vsDataType>
                  <es:earfcndl>165</es:earfcndl>
                  <es:earfcnul>19651</es:earfcnul>
                </xn:attributes>
              </xn:VsDataContainer>
            </xn:VsDataContainer>
            ..

          </xn:ManagedElement>
        </xn:MeContext>
          </xn:SubNetwork>

        </xn:SubNetwork>
      </configData>
    </bulkFile>
```

Here i want to get values for c# variables i declared which are like `subnetwork`,`sitename`,`eNBId`,`cellname`,`earfcndl` and `earfcnul`
 all the information's resides under root tag `<xn:SubNetwork id="M_ROOT">` tag,rest all for all sites coming under the root and here i am pasting only one site details.The logic is

```
   subnetwork = <xn:SubNetwork id > attribute value
    sitename  =  <xn:MeContext id> attribute value
    eNBId =  <es:eNBId> value, here the important thing is, there will be huge number of `<xn:VsDataContainer id="1">` parent tag,but the filtration is based on `<xn:vsDataType>` inner tag which is of `vsDataENodeBFunction`.
    cellname = `<xn:VsDataContainer id>` attribute value and 
    `earfcndl` and `earfcnul` is values for `<es:earfcndl> and         <es:earfcnul>` tag .Here also filtration is based on      <xn:vsDataType>vsDataEUtranCellFDD</xn:vsDataType>
```

so  i want to get `subnetwork = G-Mum,,sitename = 32509_I_East,,eNBId=32509,,cellname=BC_3250_32509_L1_B,,earfcndl=1651,,earfcnul=19651`.

Here i did following code, but got stuck and don't know what to do.But i can guarantee that this is the only way(`xmlreader` and `(XElement)XNode.ReadFrom` method) we can read 7Gb Xml file,rest all will throw "Out of memory exceptions"

```
using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(path))
                {
                    xr.MoveToContent();
                    XNamespace un = xr.LookupNamespace("un");
                    while (xr.Read())
                    {
                        while (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xr.NamespaceURI == un && xr.LocalName == "M_ROOT")
                        {
                            XElement pin = (XElement)XNode.ReadFrom(xr);
                            var data = from atts in pin.Elements(un + "attributes")
                                       select new
                                       {
                                           eNBId= (string)atts.Element(es + "eNBId"),

                                       }
                        }
                    }
```

**EDIT**
Hierarchy is   only one xn:SubNetwork id="M_ROOT" tag which contain all the regions like   which again contains all the site information's under   tag which again contains all the cell information's under  of type vsDataEUtranCellFDD

**EDIT**
@jdweng thanks for your help,now they have increased xml again,and now the snippet xml which we took by using the(XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader); itself throwing the Out of memory exception.How can i remove the unnecessary  xml part.My hierarchy is

```
<xn:SubNetwork id="M_ROOT">--------------Root
      <xn:SubNetwork id="G-Mum">---------Region
              <xn:MeContext id="32509_I_East">-----sites
                     <xn:VsDataContainer id="BC_3250_32509_L1_B"> ---Cells
                          <xn:attributes>
                            <xn:vsDataType>vsDataEUtranCellFDD</xn:vsDataType>
                    </xn:MeContext>
                  </xn:SubNetwork>
                </xn:SubNetwork>
```

SO what ever i posted on the very begging of my question is necessary data,rest all unnecessary

**EDIT**
@jdweng ,yes what ever i posted is the required on,I am editing my question again.
Heirarchy is

```
`<xn:SubNetwork>`          --------Root  and only one
```

Then after several line
    `<xn:SubNetwork>`  contain Regions will come as groups,But here only id begins with `G-` is valid so here `G-Mum`
Then   `<xn:MeContext>` contains sites will come as groups which again contains lot of `<xn:VsDataContainer>`,but here one contains child node `<xn:vsDataType>vsDataManagedElement</xn:vsDataType>` is valid one in order to get  `<es:eNBId>`.
Then again after several lines    `<xn:VsDataContainer>` of child nodes `<xn:vsDataType>vsDataEUtranCellFDD</xn:vsDataType>` contains cells will come.This(cells) is the inner most one. 
  SO there will be huge number of `<xn:VsDataContainer>` will come,out of it only of child nodes  `<xn:vsDataType>vsDataENodeBFunction</xn:vsDataType>` for getting `Enbid` and `<xn:vsDataType>vsDataEUtranCellFDD</xn:vsDataType>` for cells are import

**EDIT**
After analyzing big file i came to know that cells are coming under sites ,but i posted it in out side,Ie vsDataEUtranCellFDD is coming under the tag vsDataENodeBFunction.I have edited my xml which i posted

**EDIT 10/10/16**
There is little change in xml ,one  more `VsDataContainer` was there before `VsDataContainer` of `<xn:vsDataType>vsDataENodeBFunction</xn:vsDataType>`,Due to that `vsDataENodeBFunction` is not caught.I used `Skip(1)` but didn't work

                            
                                vsDataManagedElement

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Will there be a single `xn:SubNetwork id="M_ROOT"` element or lots of them?

Comment: @ Martin Honnen only one xn:SubNetwork id="M_ROOT" tag which contain all the regions like <xn:SubNetwork id="G-Mum">  which again contains all the site information's under  <xn:MeContext id="32509_I_East"> tag which again contains all the cell information's under <xn:VsDataContainer id="BC_3250_32509_L1_B"> of type <xn:vsDataType>vsDataEUtranCellFDD</xn:vsDataType>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a very large file so it is best to use XmlReader.  Try this code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication16
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        enum State
        {
            GET_SUBNETWORK,
            GET_MECONTEXT,
            GET_CONTAINERS,
            GET_SUBNETWORK_OR_MECONTEXT
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings() { IgnoreWhitespace = true };
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME, settings);

            reader.ReadToFollowing("SubNetwork", "generic.xsd");
            Network.network.name = reader.GetAttribute("id");
            Network.network.subnetworks = new List<SubNetwork>();

            string xnNameSpace = reader.LookupNamespace("xn");
            reader.ReadToFollowing("SubNetwork", xnNameSpace);

            Sites newSite = null;
            SubNetwork subNetWork = null;
            Boolean endElement = false;

            State state = State.GET_SUBNETWORK;
            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                switch (state)
                {
                    case State.GET_SUBNETWORK:
                        if (reader.Name != "xn:SubNetwork")
                        {
                            reader.ReadToFollowing("SubNetwork", xnNameSpace);
                        }
                        if (!reader.EOF)
                        {
                            subNetWork = new SubNetwork();
                            Network.network.subnetworks.Add(subNetWork);
                            subNetWork.name = reader.GetAttribute("id");
                            subNetWork.sites = new List<Sites>();

                            state = State.GET_MECONTEXT;
                        }
                        break;

                    case State.GET_MECONTEXT :
                        if (reader.Name != "xn:MeContext")
                        {
                            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
                            {
                                endElement = true;
                                state = State.GET_SUBNETWORK;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                endElement = false;
                                reader.ReadToFollowing("MeContext", xnNameSpace);
                            }
                        }
                        if (!reader.EOF && !endElement)
                        {
                            state = State.GET_CONTAINERS;
                            newSite = new Sites();
                            subNetWork.sites.Add(newSite);
                            newSite.sitename = reader.GetAttribute("id");
                            reader.ReadToFollowing("ManagedElement", xnNameSpace);
                            reader.ReadToFollowing("VsDataContainer", xnNameSpace);
                        }
                        break;

                    case State.GET_CONTAINERS:

                        if (!reader.EOF)
                        {
                            switch (reader.NodeType)
                            {
                                case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                                    state = State.GET_SUBNETWORK_OR_MECONTEXT;
                                    break;
                                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                                    string text = reader.ReadContentAsString();
                                    break;

                                case XmlNodeType.Element:

                                    string elementName = reader.Name;
                                    XElement element = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                                    if (elementName == "xn:VsDataContainer")
                                    {
                                        XElement vsDataENodeBFunction = element.Descendants().Where(a => a.Name.LocalName == "vsDataENodeBFunction").FirstOrDefault();
                                        if (vsDataENodeBFunction != null)
                                        {                                            
                                            XElement eNBId = element.Descendants().Where(a => a.Name.LocalName == "eNBId").FirstOrDefault();
                                            if (eNBId != null)
                                            {
                                                newSite.eNBId = (int)eNBId;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        List<XElement> vsDataContainers = element.Descendants().Where(a => a.Name.LocalName == "VsDataContainer").ToList();
                                        List<XElement> vsDataEUtranCellFDD = vsDataContainers.Where(x => x.Descendants().Where(a => (a.Name.LocalName == "vsDataType") && ((string)a == "vsDataEUtranCellFDD")).Any()).ToList();
                                        if (vsDataEUtranCellFDD.Any())
                                        {
                                            List<CellName> cells = vsDataEUtranCellFDD.Select(x => new CellName()
                                            {
                                                id = (string)x.Attribute("id"),
                                                earfcndl = (int)x.Descendants().Where(a => a.Name.LocalName == "earfcndl").FirstOrDefault(),
                                                earfcnul = (int)x.Descendants().Where(a => a.Name.LocalName == "earfcnul").FirstOrDefault()
                                            }).ToList();
                                            if (newSite.cellName == null)
                                            {
                                                newSite.cellName = new List<CellName>();
                                            }
                                            newSite.cellName.AddRange(cells);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    break;

                                default:
                                    Console.WriteLine("Unexpected Results");
                                    string elementText = reader.ReadContentAsString();
                                    Console.ReadLine();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        break;

                    case State.GET_SUBNETWORK_OR_MECONTEXT :
                        switch(reader.NodeType)
                        {
                            case XmlNodeType.Element :
                                switch(reader.Name)
                                {
                                    case "xn:MeContext" :
                                        state = State.GET_MECONTEXT;
                                        break;
                                    case "xn:SubNetwork" :
                                        state = State.GET_SUBNETWORK;
                                        break;
                                    default :
                                        reader.ReadStartElement();
                                        break;
                                }
                                break;

                            case XmlNodeType.Text:
                                string text = reader.ReadContentAsString();
                                break;

                            case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                                reader.ReadEndElement();
                                break;

                            default:
                                Console.WriteLine("Unexpected Results");
                                string elementText = reader.ReadContentAsString();
                                Console.ReadLine();
                                break;

                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    public class Network
    {
        public static Network network = new Network();
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<SubNetwork> subnetworks { get; set; }
    }
    public class SubNetwork
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<Sites> sites { get; set; }

    }
    public class Sites
    {
        public string sitename { get; set; }
        public int eNBId { get; set; }
        public List<CellName> cellName { get; set; }
    }
    public class CellName
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public int earfcndl { get; set; }
        public int earfcnul { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: that is great i will try and get back you

Comment: I made a slight change.  CellName when debugging I change a Select to a Where and didn't do same in eNBId.  See modified code.

Comment: eNBId  value i am getting "1" which should be "32509" probably the hierarchy has some issues or namespace

Comment: i edited my question,This is not working for multiple cell names,only one cellname value it is giving.If we have multiple sitesnames  begins with <xn:MeContext tag how to get all site info,even till <xn:SubNetwork id=""> How to get all inofos coming coming under the groups.Do we need to use groupdBy() or loop??

Comment: Fixed.  It is hard to tell with xml files which elements repeat and which don't when only a small piece of the file is provided.  It is better to at least post two of each repeating element.

Comment: great, i modifed question with two cellnames BC_3250_32509_L1_B and DF_3250_32509_L1_G and mandatory condition is <xn:vsDataType>vsDataEUtranCellFDD</xn:vsDataType> ,but cellname collection is not added.I have tested site collection which is working fine.

Comment: I change a FirstOrDefault() to a ToList() which should get all the cellnames.  Also changed Class to make it a List<> object.

Comment: ,thanks a lot,, the problem now having is if <xn:vsDataType> is of different than vsDataEUtranCellFDD,then also it is adding which should not happen,so it should satisfy <xn:vsDataType>vsDataEUtranCellFDD</xn:vsDataType> which is in different schema, i modified my question by adding cellname CC_3250_32509_L1_C

Comment: I made changes.  These are typical parse errors that I've seen lots of times especially with large files.

Comment: thanks for your help,now they have increased xml again,and now the snippet xml which we took by using the(XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader); itself throwing the Out of memory exception.I have edited my question

Comment: Why do people generate data without a method to read the data?  Creating a large file that can't be read is !@#$%.  Do they still have a 2nd level Subnet?  I guess we can move to the lower level subnet and do the parsing.

Comment: This is a machine generated file given by Telecom provider,.If we move to the lower level subnet what advantage we will get? how can we reduce it that level or do we have any alternate way?

Comment: Since this is a 6 GB+ file i cant open it in editor and examine,Can you tell me how to skip the first subnet,it seems it will work ,let me test it

Comment: I had to go to a meeting, otherwise I would of posted the change an hour ago.

Comment: i checked the big file generated, and confirmed that even if we skip it will throw out of memory exception.How to overcome that issue?

Comment: I don't understand you last comment.  The code will give memory error if we read an element that is very large.  I assumed the xml file had two nested levels of the element SubNet like you original posting.  I assumed the top level Subnet was the entire file and the child Subnet was a small pieces that would not create a memory error.I think the file format has changed.  I need to see what the xml really looks like.I think you should be able to write a quick c# application that reads 1000 lines of the xml with streamreader and save to a file.  Then you should be able to read file with notepad.

Comment: Peter: I say the duplicate posting.  I need to see a small piece of the updated xml to help.  Without know the exact structure of the xml I can't give a good solution.  I suspect one of the SubNetwork tags was eliminated or changed.  We need to parse file using an element that is smaller than the SubNetWork tag.

Comment: if we do the same way you mentioned in second answer and meanwhile do the first operation,Does that work. Instead of 10000,it will be infinite and overwrite the same file

Comment: I only wanted to use 2nd method to be able to look at xml so we can modify 1st method. You said you weren't able to read the large xml so the output will produce a smaller file that we can read.  I made the output file a 'txt' file so it didn't overwrite original file.  The solution is to read a smaller portion of the xml using the ReadFrom() method.   The only other solution is to use XmlReader to read on element at a time and the code isn't pretty.

Comment: How to copy a xml file starting from <xn:SubNetwork id="G-Mum"> and for 10000 lines??

Comment: Lets try again.  This should get rid of memory error.

Comment: no luck at all .Certain subnetworks coming under the main subnetwork are very large.Even when i run with X64 it was taking time and not coming out.The only thing i note in x64 is, it is not throwing any out of memory exception.Any other logic by spliiting in to seperate file as you mentioned

Comment: Something must be working.  I just looking at the VsDataContainer but not sure how to group the containers.  Right now I don't know if the sample xml you posted is still accurate.  There are lots of ways I can solve issue(s), but need to know if the code posted is still accurate and what class structures you want.

Comment: ,yes what ever i posted is the required on,I have edited my question,see my last edits

Comment: Can you post portion of xml since it is different from posted xml.  The posted code has the two subnets are on consecutive lines.  I think I have a way of getting the code to work.

Comment: I think I got it.

Comment: Thanks for your help.something wrong somewhere, it read completely but few subnetworks are missing and for read one only one site and one cell name are added rest all skipped

Comment: I was expecting that.  I'm trying to keep code as simple as possible and still get correct results.  It means that the element MeContext has other elements besides VsDataContainer.  The sample code you posted only had VsDataContainer.  I changed code but it is a little bit more complicated.

Comment: I think the old code was working but putting some VsDataContainer in wrong SubNetwork.  In the new code I'm expecting at least one VsDataContainer in every MeContext.  If not, then VsDataContainer will end up in wrong SubNet and a SubNet will be lost.

Comment: thanks for your help,After analyzing big file i came to know that cells are coming under sites ,but i posted it in out side,Ie <xn:vsDataType>vsDataEUtranCellFDD</xn:vsDataType>  is coming under the tag <xn:vsDataType>vsDataENodeBFunction</xn:vsDataType>.I have edited my question

Comment: It looks like there is two nested elements VsDataContainer.  Is all the data in the child VsDataContainer?  Do you want any changes to the classes to handle the nested VsDataContainer tags?

Comment: I realized with your latest xml that code could be missing some sites.   Fixed code.  Still if issues please answer previous questions.

Comment: sorry for changing xml again, There is little change in xml ,one more VsDataContainer was there before VsDataContainer of <xn:vsDataType>vsDataENodeBFunction</xn:vsDataType>,Due to that vsDataENodeBFunction is not caught.I used Skip(1) but didn't work vsDataManagedElement.I have edited my question

Comment: Don't understand the issue.  All the data is in the classes with the xml posted.  Number and order of VsDataContainer doesn't make a difference with latest code.

Comment: extremely sorry VsDataContainer immediately after Mecontext,I have edited my xml

Comment: You can test the xml i posted with the code you posted.I was trying to skip to next desentent with Skip() linq way,

Comment: Double check your last change. There are two nested levels of VsDataContainer.  It looks like after Mecontext there is one VsDataContainer.  Then you have ManagedElement and there is two layers of VsDataContainer under ManagedElement.  Is this correct?

Comment: under Mecontext  ,there are two layers of VsDataContainer ,one immediate and another one under xn:ManagedElement where all cells resides

Comment: I just changed the search for element Mecontext to ManagedElement

Comment: that is great ,but only one site and cell are taken and rest all skipped.How to fix that issue

Comment: There is only one site in the xml with two cells.   Where is 2nd site?

Comment: sorry i posted a small part of 7GB file,The herirachy is Group of Regions(Subenetworks) contains group of Sites which again contains cells

Comment: I need to know where the missing items are located.  Add examples of missing site(s) without removing existing items.

Comment: Are you saying there is more than one MeContext in each SubNetwork?

Comment: yes we will have lot of sites(MeContext ) .as of now one one site it is taking from each region

Comment: Edited my template to include one more sites in the xml file

Comment: Fixed one more time?

Comment: thats great it is working .but i am testing several times before accepting answer

Comment: can you replace Descendants with Elements

Comment: Yes, if you have the parent of the elements.  Elements just gets the immediate children while descendants gets the child and all grandchildren (as well as great grand children).

Comment: Then can you change the exisitng code which you posted with Elements instead of Descentants.. iam not getting any value if i use elements instead of descentants like  earfcndl = (int?)x.Elements(esNs + "earfcndl").FirstOrDefault(),

Comment: Look at the solution I did this year.  I got the intermediate element attribute : XElement attributes = vsDataContainer.Element(xnNs + "attributes");  Then used earfcndl = (int?)attributes.Element(esNs + "earfcndl"),

Comment: i deleted that answer rather to continue with this anwer and modify

Comment: I added new answer to solve earfcndl and earfcnul.  There may be some minor typos in posted code, but it should be very close.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code to get a small portion of xml

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApplication17
{
    class Program
    {
        const string inputFilename = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string outputFilename = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        const int COPY_LINES = 10000;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inputFilename, Encoding.UTF8);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputFilename, false,  Encoding.UTF8);
            Boolean start = false;
            int i = 0;
            while (i < COPY_LINES)
            {
                string inputLine = reader.ReadLine();
                if(inputLine.Contains("xn:SubNetwork id=\"G-Mum\""))
                {
                    start = true;
                }
                if (start)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(inputLine);
                    i++;
                }
            }
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(1000000);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below should fix the issue with earfcndl and earfcnul

```
 List<CellName> cells = new List<CellName>(); ;
                                            foreach (XElement xelement in vsDataEUtranCellFDD)
                                            {

                                                CellName newCell = new CellName();
                                                newCell.id = (string)xelement.Attribute("id");
                                                XElement attribute = xelement.Descendants().Where(a => a.Name.LocalName == "vsDataEUtranCellFDD").FirstOrDefault();

                                                newCell.earfcndl = (int?)attribute.Elements().Where(a => a.Name.LocalName == "earfcndl").FirstOrDefault();
                                                newCell.earfcnul = (int)attribute.Elements().Where(a => a.Name.LocalName == "earfcnul").FirstOrDefault();
        cells.Add(newCell);
     }
}
```

Comment: i am getting an errror like "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: element".i modified your answer

Comment: You have to make (int?) and change type in class to int?  Not all cells have earfcndl and earfcnul.

Comment: I just added test for attribute = null

Comment: @ jdweng i got it thanks, i am modifying your answer